# Neither Fabric for Android nor twitter4j find tweets containing a specific user's mention

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to retrieve tweets that mention an specific user either using fabric for android or twitter4j, but I'm not getting anything.

-With Fabric for Android I'm doing it with "twitterApiClient.getSearchService().tweets" (logged in as a guest previously)

-With twitter4j, this is my code:

```
 public List<Long> twList (String user){
    List<Long> listTw = new ArrayList<>();
    lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int tamano = 0;
    ArrayList<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();
    String mention = "@"+user.trim();
    query = new Query(user);
    while (tweets.size() < numberOfTweets) {
        tamano = tweets.size();
        if (numberOfTweets - tweets.size() > 100) {
            query.setCount(100);
        } else {
            query.setCount(numberOfTweets - tweets.size());
        }
        try {
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());
            Log.d("App", "Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets");
            for (Status t : tweets) {
                if (t.getId() < lastID) {
                    lastID = t.getId();
                }
            }
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            Log.d("App", "Couldn't connect: " + te);
        }
        query.setMaxId(lastID - 1);
        if (tamano == tweets.size()) break;
    }
    for (Status s: tweets){
        if (s.getText().matches(mention)){
            listTw.add(s.getId());
            Log.d("App", s.getText());
        }
    }
    tweets.clear();
    return listTw;
}
```

When I look for the username on Twitter website, I get those tweets where it's mentioned.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

When was the last time a Tweet including the username you're searching for, posted? The Search API (which is used by both Fabric and Twitter4j) only covers around 7 days of data. The website has the complete archive, but that is not available in the public Twitter API.

Comment: The last post was two months ago, that's the problem then, I didn't know that. So it's not a coding error.. Is there a way to get older posts? Thanks in advance

Comment: The public search API from Twitter has never provided more than 7 days of data history. If you want to retrieve more than that programmatically, I'm afraid you would need to look at the commercial Gnip products from Twitter.